# E/audit: type=1701 audit(1533068627.416:106978) error in android studio

Tags: android

I am developing an android app , sometimes I get this error and the app crashes and this is the log:

```
 08-01 00:53:47.426 2501-2501/? E/audit: type=1701 
 audit(1533068627.416:106978): auid=4294967295 uid=10781 gid=10781 
 ses=4294967295 subj=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 pid=27042 
 comm="RenderThread" exe="/system/bin/app_process32" sig=6[ 08-01 
 00:53:47.432  2356: 2356 W/         ]
 debuggerd: resuming target 26966
```

I think maybe It is because of memory leak ,can some one tell me what is it for?

Comment: there should be more to it. could you add some more from the crash log

Comment: @AvinashRavilla other logs are different each time , this is the only line that is common in each crashes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution myself ,I have a viewpager and a map in one fragment and this error was happening when the method onStop in map executed,in [this link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37123764) comment #76 about map helped me to solve my problem. :)